# How to loop through items of a recordset?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, xmlhttprequest

So I am trying to make an inventory manager that on click of a button, it selects rows from a table from a database. I currently have the raw recordset which is

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Tyler","last_name":"Marlow","hooks_id":1,"sp_id":1,"rods_id":1,"num_hooks":10,"num_sp":30},{"id":2,"first_name":"Jon","last_name":"Marlow","hooks_id":2,"sp_id":1,"rods_id":1,"num_hooks":50,"num_sp":200}]
```

However, I just want to print the values after the colon. For example:
1 Tyler Marlow 1 1 1 10 30

Here is the code that prints the record set

server.js

```
app.get('/addPerson', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM person";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send(recordset);
            }
        });
        conn.close();
    });
});
```

And here is the xmlhttp request to use the recordset

index.html

```
<script>
        function displayPerson() {
           // console.log('test');
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var person = xhttp.responseText;
                    var element = document.getElementById("PersonContainer");
                    element.innerHTML = person;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "/AddPerson", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

I would appreciate any help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object values using Object.values(obj) method.

```
var result = JSON.parse(person).map((item) => Object.values(item))
console.log(result);
element.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Do I just need to import something?

Comment: Updated the code. Can you console.log(person) in your code and see what it looks like?